# SQL Trigger is Updating random row not the joined row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in a update trigger

```
UPDATE [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] 
SET 
    Defendant_1 = i.DisplayName 
    , Loan_Number_1 = i.Comments 
    , Client = i.KS_BookName 
    , Date_Instructed = i.OpenDate 
    , Person_Responsible_name = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerName 
    , Person_Responsible_Email = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerEmail 
    , Person_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
    , Person_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
    , Agent_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
    , Agent_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
    , CBA_Panel_Service_Area = i.KS_ServiceCat 
    , HBN_Number = i.KS_ClientAcctRef 
    , St_George_Contact = i.KS_Instructor 
FROM 
    [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] c
INNER JOIN 
    Inserted i
ON
    Left(c.file_number, 6) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = i.MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

[image]
Now the Join connection matches up on the File_Number e.g. 70003-1 but for some unknown reason the data that should be updated to this Row is been updated to a toally random row 614864-7

I can continue to execute the trigger and tring to update the 70003-1 row but i continues to update the other row  614864-7

This is also running across a linked server the trigger is on one server up dating the other servers

Server tigger sits on Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (X64)   Feb 10 2007 00:59:02   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Server trigger is updating Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (X64)   Feb 10 2007 00:59:02   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

I have been thinking that updating the servers SP to SP4 may fix the problem?

Does anyone have a reson why this might be haapening the Server

Ammendment

Yeah i actually hardcoded the values and simplified the SQL Statement it works as it should

```
DECLARE @MatterNumber as varchar(50)
SET @MatterNumber = (SELECT i.MAtternumber FRom Inserted as i) + '-1'
Print @MatterNumber

UPDATE [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] 
       SET Loan_Number_1 = ‘123’
       WHERE file_number =  @MatterNumber
```

But as soon as I set a Declared Varible value to Loan_Number_1 or any of the other columes this is when the problem starts to happen

```
DECLARE @LoanNumber as varchar(50)
SET @LoanNumber =    (SELECT i.Comments FRom Inserted as i)
    Print @LoanNumber
DECLARE @MatterNumber as varchar(50)
SET @MatterNumber = (SELECT i.MAtternumber FRom Inserted as i) + '-1'

Print @MatterNumber –-I print here I see 70003-1

UPDATE [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] 
       SET Loan_Number_1 = @LoanNumber

       WHERE file_number =  @MatterNumber

Print @MatterNumber –-I print here I see 70003-1
```

Comment: I very much doubt it's an issue with SQL server itself - most likely there is an error in your trigger code

Comment: I agree with Charleh. Why don't you try a few different things to isolate the problem like: 1. Hardcode your trigger and see if it behaves as expected 2. Write the Inserted table out to another table and inspect afterwards. You know that if you update more that one row, the trigger will be called with multiple rows in the Inserted table?

Comment: I have ammended my quest to show how i hardcoded and what this showed me

Comment: You update Loan_Number_1, Client, Date_Instructed etc. but on the screenshot column Loan_Number_1 both records different. Interesting why?

Comment: All of your code assumes that INSERTED will only ever contain one record - you most definitely cannot assume this. I you add code to your simplified working trigger until it misbehaves and that will let you identify the issue.

Also you might want to try dumping the contents of the INSERTED table into a local (not linked server) table and see how it looks. Using a trigger to update a remote server is not considered reliable. Normally you write to a log table on the local server and then have another process copy that to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] 
SET 
    Defendant_1 = i.DisplayName 
    , Loan_Number_1 = i.Comments 
    , Client = i.KS_BookName 
    , Date_Instructed = i.OpenDate 
    , Person_Responsible_name = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerName 
    , Person_Responsible_Email = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerEmail 
    , Person_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
    , Person_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
    , Agent_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
    , Agent_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
    , CBA_Panel_Service_Area = i.KS_ServiceCat 
    , HBN_Number = i.KS_ClientAcctRef 
    , St_George_Contact = i.KS_Instructor 
FROM

    Inserted i
where
    Left([FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] .file_number, 6) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = i.MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: No that didnt work either it also wouldnt allow the [FSSQLPROD01].[collectionsDELETE].[dbo].[collections] in the left function

Answer (score -4):

Triggers are for update on a single record. They dont work when we do bulk insertion/update.
Because `SQL Server triggers runs only 1 time per UPDATE.`
Your trigger will not fire 3000 times if you are modifying 3000 rows in a single statement. Your trigger will fire only once. So this is why it is updating the random row(although it should be the 1st row).

Comment: This is completely, absolutely false

Comment: Actually its mostly true. If I run a single update and it updates 3000 rows then the trigger will fire once and INSERTED will have 3000 rows in it. This may or may not be why the update appears to be random.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Fair enough, that is the only right part of the answer. The *Triggers are for update on a single record* is wrong, that they don't work for updates or inserts for more than one record is wrong, the "updating a random row and it should be the first" is wrong. Overall, this answer is wrong

Comment: Agreed - taken in total that answer is misleading and incorrect.